# Android Tv - Losing Focus in Details Fragment

Tags: android, android-tv, television, leanback

I am developing a Android Tv application using `lean-back` library. I am losing focus when pressing down in `DPAD`. Description is not seeing completely. First Focus going to Action Row and then navigate to the last Row . How to give focus to the description ? I am using `FullWidthDetailsOverviewRowPresenter` and `DetailsDescriptionPresenter` for the Details page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use FullWidthDetailsOverviewSharedElementHelper and assign it as listener to  FullWidthDetailsOverviewRowPresenter . The trick is to change focus by changing the position of the thumbnail image in details view.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. I've included the helper and set it as the listener for the presenter but it hasn't resolved the problem. Is there more to this solution?

Comment: post your code in a question and link me to it. I"ll check and update you

Comment: Thanks, I've asked the question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322391/leanback-detailsfragment-not-scrolling-as-expected I've linked the entire fragment source just in case.